# Realm Java - How to detach of context an object after query

Tags: realm

How can I perform a query and change any property about this object but not persist this modification?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Realm objects are tied to the Realm files, and therefore the object's setters cannot be called outside a write transaction. Of course, you can begin a write transaction and cancel it but that will lead the Realm (and it's objects unchanged).

The best option is to copy the values of the fields/properties to a stand-alone object and modify that instead.